# Trouble with osmocom source

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, hackrf

I'm having trouble running a simple flowgraph with an [osmocom](https://osmocom.org) source and a qt gui sink. If I run the file with a waveform generator instead of the osmocom source, all is well, the plots appear as they should, no problem.

When the osmocom source is hooked up, everything runs and there is no immediate error message... the gui window just never opens. If I run it from the terminal, I get the following:

```
import 'osmosdr._osmosdr_swig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cae23c8>
import 'osmosdr.osmosdr_swig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cdda978>
import 'osmosdr' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0cdc9dd8>
```

Not sure what those errors mean but it just hangs there. Eventually it ends up using 100% of CPU and I have to CTRL + \ it to get it to stop.

- Is it a library maybe in the wrong place that it's not finding?

Please let me know if I can post any more info but:

- OS : Ubuntu 18.04
- Gnuradio-config-info -version : 3.8.0.0-rc2
- gr-osmosdr was installed from the git repo and the gr3.8 branch (which worked for me previously)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!